# Android - Starting random Activity error?

Tags: java, android, debugging, random, android-activity

I have 5 different activities and on every activities there should be a random number generator so the user goes to a random activity.

Example:
 
Act.1 ---> Act. 3
Act.3 ---> Act. 4
Act.2 ---> Act. 5
Note: So from Activity 5 the user should not be able to go back to a previous activity.

So this what I wrote in each activity to go to random activity, I made some variables so the next activity the user goes to, the next activity will know the previous activities the user visited before.
This is the first activity where the user will start.

```
public void on_quiz_1_wrong(View v){
     score =  score - 2;
     String visited = "1";
     txtScore.setText(String.valueOf(score) );
     int r1 = r.nextInt(4)+1;

     if(r1 == 1){
         Intent q1 = new Intent(this,Quiz_2.class);
         Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
         bundle1.putString("passVisit", visited);
         q1.putExtras(bundle1);
         q1.putExtra("passScore", score);
         startActivity(q1);
     }

     else if(r1 == 2){
         Intent q1 = new Intent(this,Quiz_3.class);
         Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
         bundle1.putString("passVisit", visited);
         q1.putExtras(bundle1);
         q1.putExtra("passScore", score);
         startActivity(q1);
     }

     else if(r1 == 3){
         Intent q1 = new Intent(this,Quiz_4.class);
         Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
         bundle1.putString("passVisit", visited); // visited = 1 ...> string value
         q1.putExtras(bundle1);
         q1.putExtra("passScore", score);
         startActivity(q1);
     }

     else if(r1 == 4){
         Intent q1 = new Intent(this,Quiz_5.class);
         Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
         bundle1.putString("passVisit", visited);
         q1.putExtras(bundle1);
         q1.putExtra("passScore", score);
         startActivity(q1);
     }
```

And, that's another piece of code, I put in each activities so now the activity knows the previous visit so the random number generator should not generate a number where the user already visited.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz_3);

    txtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q_result);   // declaring the TextView 
    correctB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quiz_3_correct);
    wrongB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quiz_3_wrong);

    r = new Random();

    // Getting previous score
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (extras != null) 
     {
       score   = extras.getInt("passScore");
    }

    txtScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));

    Bundle getBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    last_visit = getBundle.getString("passVisit"); // If previous was quiz 1 the---> last_visit is = 1



} // end of onCreate
```

And if the user wants to get to a random activity from the previous one:

```
public void on_quiz_3_wrong(View v){
     score =  score - 2;
     String visited = "3";
     txtScore.setText(String.valueOf(score) );
     int r1 = r.nextInt(4)+1;

     if(r1 == 2 &&  !last_visit.equals("2") ){
         Intent q1 = new Intent(this,Quiz_2.class);
         Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
         bundle1.putString("passVisit", visited);
         q1.putExtras(bundle1);          
         q1.putExtra("passScore", score);
         startActivity(q1);
     }



     if(r1 == 4 && !last_visit.equals("4") ){
         Intent q1 = new Intent(this,Quiz_4.class);
         Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
         bundle1.putString("passVisit", visited);
         q1.putExtras(bundle1);
         q1.putExtra("passScore", score);
         startActivity(q1);
     }

     if(r1 == 5 &&  !last_visit.equals("5") ){
         Intent q1 = new Intent(this,Quiz_5.class);
         Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
         bundle1.putString("passVisit", visited);
         q1.putExtras(bundle1);
         q1.putExtra("passScore", score);
         startActivity(q1);

     }
```

}

I know this is long and i am sorry but i am trying to give you as much details as possible, because i know it's a bit confusing.

I was trying to get this working since September, still no luck, I would be very happy.
Thank you!!!

Comment: What is your problem, exactly? Does the app crash, if so post the stacktrace. What doesn't work properly?

Comment: You'll have to tell us what the actual issue is, I can't wade through all that unformatted code easily. What isn't working?

Comment: first, the app crashes, and the random system does not work even if the crash would dissapear!

Comment: it's more like the random system.

Comment: Example: 
Act.1 ---> Act. 3 <br />
Act.3 ---> Act. 4 <br />
Act.2 ---> Act. 5<br />
Note: So from Activity 5 the user should not be able to go back to a previous activity.

Comment: @user2547460 Try to finish each activity before going to any other activity.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace? What does the random system do wrong? Does it keeping generating the same numbers?

Comment: no, the problem is that, it still can go to an activity that has already been visited by the user

Comment: @GrIsHu is right, call finish(); after startActivity() to actually kill the previous activity.

Comment: so just write finish("name of intent")???

Comment: @GrIsHu answered the question correctly: finish() kills the current activity, if you don't call finish() the user can return to it by pressing the back key. For more information about these kind go to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to finish your all previous activity before going to any other activity as below:

```
 if(r1 == 1){
         Intent q1 = new Intent(this,Quiz_2.class);
         Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
         bundle1.putString("passVisit", visited);
         q1.putExtras(bundle1);
         q1.putExtra("passScore", score);
         startActivity(q1);
         finish();
     }

     else if(r1 == 2){
         Intent q1 = new Intent(this,Quiz_3.class);
         Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
         bundle1.putString("passVisit", visited);
         q1.putExtras(bundle1);
         q1.putExtra("passScore", score);
         startActivity(q1);
          finish();
     }

     else if(r1 == 3){
         Intent q1 = new Intent(this,Quiz_4.class);
         Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
         bundle1.putString("passVisit", visited); // visited = 1 ...> string value
         q1.putExtras(bundle1);
         q1.putExtra("passScore", score);
         startActivity(q1);
          finish();
     }

     else if(r1 == 4){
         Intent q1 = new Intent(this,Quiz_5.class);
         Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
         bundle1.putString("passVisit", visited);
         q1.putExtras(bundle1);
         q1.putExtra("passScore", score);
         startActivity(q1);
          finish();
     }
```

Comment: but it's not the back arrow key, it's when the user clicks on the on_quiz_3_wrong button, then the app should navigate the user to a new activity, the user didn't visit yet

Comment: You better clarify your question what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @user2547460 Do not modify my answer with your log. Post it in your question.

Comment: I accepted your answer, please vote up for my question, because now i cannot ask any more questions! please

Comment: I am sorry my vote for your question is locked. I can not vote now.